# How to prepare an installation of Java app for Steam?

Tags: java, installation, jvm, javafx-8, steam

I have some trouble about installing my application developed in Java for Steam platform. Steam requires that a Java application includes a JRE for running.

Initially, I created a simple batch that installed a JRE provided by myself, before installing the app.

As Steam rejecting the batch,I created a bundle including the JRE and my app. That is rejected too.

My problem is that any app commonly provided to the Steam platform is not developed in Java. And Steam has some difficulty to help me with accuracy,for instance about "installscripts".

So, have you already installed your game in the Steam environment? If yes, could you share your experience?

Thanks in advance